# Looking for a low boiling point solvent for MAPI precursors (Lead Iodide (II) and Methylammonium Iodide)

Tags: solubility, organometallic-compounds

Things I have thought of till now:

1. Acetonitrile with HI additive
2. Acetonitrile with DMSO additive

The problem with the first would be that HI is in an around 55% aqueous solution and water doesn't play well with the perovskite. Meanwhile, the second might end up needing enough DMSO to drastically increase the boiling point. I am not sure about the second and intend to try it out and will post updates when I am done.